# Ruby on Rails Bootstrap undefined method `start_with?' for /bootstrap\/glyphicons-halflings-regular\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/:Regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

First of all, good forum to all.
I'm trying to make a simple forum site with Ruby on Rails and I decided to use bootstrap as a css library and I successfully installed it.

However, although there is no error in the installation, when I go to the required route, I get the following error:
[Error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITwlf.png)

Console Error:

```rb
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 3.0.1-p64) ("Zawgyi")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 101375
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-12-13 19:43:58 +0300
   (2.7ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 366)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 85.1ms | Allocations: 5391)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 173ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms | Allocations: 14529)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `start_with?' for /bootstrap\/glyphicons-halflings-regular\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/:Regexp):
  
sprockets (4.0.2) lib/sprockets/uri_utils.rb:78:in `valid_asset_uri?'
sprockets (4.0.2) lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:27:in `resolve'
sprockets (4.0.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:79:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.0.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (4.0.2) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `block in synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:363:in `run_task'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `loop'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `catch'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block in create_worker'
```

`application.html.erb`:

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
      <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Ruby on Rails"%>
    </title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    
    <!-- This refers to app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss-->
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="conteiner">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Rails on Forum</h1>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <section class="right">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class=""></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kaydol</a></li>
            <li class=""></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oturum aç</a></li>
            <li class="#"></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <%= yield%>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance to my teachers who will help.

Comment: did you config assets.precompile with a Regex ?, it looks like [Sprockets 3+ deprecated precompile filters such as regexps and procs](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/269)

Comment: I don't know how you said